# R Script in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm running through an issue when running my R Script in Power BI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKEGe.png)

I have tried to replace all null values by '' but still having the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your script run correctly outside Power BI?

Comment: Yes James it does run correctly.

Comment: @MOL Would you care to share a sample of your data and a code snippet?